# Ubuntu equivalent of system restore? Does it exist?

Tags: installation, restore, opera

Ubuntu n00b here.

I have created several disasters of the first order already.

I am getting ready to try to install opera - it is a very long and arduous process.  I am afraid - no - I am absolutely certain that I will damage something important.

How do I create a system restore point?  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu offers the same services to take snapshots of your computer when changes are made and the [Back in Time](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/backintime-gnome/) application for Linux is a great tool to achieve the same easy-to-use GUI. The program utilizes existing services including rsync for creating and applying restore snapshots and diff for monitoring system changes.
Back in Time allows you to backup all folders and restore any folders with write access in the event of a problem following a system change.

To install it from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) use next command:

```
sudo apt-get install backintime-common backintime-gnome
```

[image: Install Back in Time]

Comment: Source: http://beginlinux.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/back-in-time-system-restore-on-ubuntu/