# Reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 from Scratch

Tags: 18.04

I am actually with Ubuntu 18.04, but there is too much scrap. I would like to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 without using an ISO file. I would like to reinstall it directly from the terminal. Is it something doable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu equivalent of system restore? Does it exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291027/ubuntu-equivalent-of-system-restore-does-it-exist)

Comment: Too much scrap?   Packages can be `install --reinstall` which seems to be what you're after, but it's not quite the same effect as a re-install via booting an ISO (which itself can be done many ways; clean or new system, or re-install without overwriting data & user settings/configs etc)

Comment: It  is because I switch from French to English, but all the Download are still heading to ''Téléchargement'' instead of ''Download''. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know any way to do it without an iso.

I can suggest you see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how) site, to install ubuntu from windows without a CD or a USB. You can do it from windows, and maybe even from linux also(UNetbootin have a linux download).
I dont know if you can install from the same SO that you want to unistall, but you can try it, or maybe search more about the UNetbootin program.